# Defining a List and then Binding to a Data Grid View

Tags: c#, binding

I am attempting to define a list and then assign it to a Data Grid View:

```
    var list = new[]
{ 
    new { Number = 10, Name = "Smith" },
    new { Number = 10, Name = "John" } 
}.ToList();

var bindingList = new BindingList(list);
var source = new BindingSource(bindingList, null);
dgvResult.DataSource = source;
```

I know my problems stem from new BindingList(list) - do I need to define the type?

Answer (score 0):

Why the BindingList?
Following code works:

```
    var list = new[]
    {   
        new{Number = 10, Name="John"},
        new {Number=20, Name="Smith"}
    }.ToList();

    dataGridViewList.DataSource = list;
```

Hopefully it helps...